# Benefits to hosting Git in VSTS vs Github?

Tags: git

I have been looking around for some documentation on the benefits (or caveats) to hosting a Git Repo in Visual Studio Online vs Github. Are they basically interchangeable? I am just referring to personal projects without many collaborators.

Comment: VSTS = Visual Studio Team System?

Comment: Just use gitlab.com. Unlimited private repos

Comment: For pure Git without issue tracking, managing access, etc. it doesn't really matter much which hosting software you use. It's only when you start using the more advanced functionality that you need a good idea of what you want. Do you have any idea of additional functionality you want?

Comment: @giraff VSTS = "Visual Studio Team Services"

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your projects and what do you want to do with them. As far as just git repository functionality they are almost the same. One of the benefits of Visual Studio Team Services is that it provides build server and is good for larger teams because of its integration of User stories. However, it comes at a price if your projects grow: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/visual-studio-team-services/?cdn=disable and I am not sure if there is a limit to some projects you have.

For Github, you can use it for free (if you don't mind it being public) and a subscription fee for having private repositories is pretty cheap. If you are looking to have a build server for GitHub, you can use third-party websites for this purpose: https://github.com/integrations/feature/continuous-integration

In general, I prefer to use GitHub for my projects because I don't use most of the features of visual studio online and it is a lot cheaper.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using it only on this one computer, you can use git. Github basically is a hosting server for git repositories. All code hosted there is public (unless you pay for it).

Comment: But I get free Visual Studio Online, so is there any benefit with one over the other?